# Should I write unit test for the @KafkaListener

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka, junit, integration-testing, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer which uses `@KafkaListener`. But the listener does nothing except receiving the message and pass it to private method to do the necessary things. My question is I am wondering whether I need to write integration testing to see listener is working or just the unit test. If I write unit test again the `@KafkaListener` annotated method is not doing much and just pass the message to relevant private method. So in that case, I cannot write unit tests for private methods. See below receiver code.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
class KafkaConsumerService {

    @KafkaListener(
        groupId = "#{groupId('listener')}",
        topics = ["#{pubTopic('someTopic')}"]
    )
    fun process(@Payload message: EventMessage) {
        log.info("Received a message > ")
        when (message.type) {
            Type1 -> processMessageType1(message.type1Mesage)
            Type2 -> processMessageType2(message.type2Mesage)
            else -> log.info("unhandled type ")
        }
    }

    private fun processMessageType1(message: Type1Mesage) {
        log.warn("Received a Type1Mesage " )
        val someClassObj = SomeClass()
        someClassObj.publicMethod(message)
    }

    private fun processMessageType2(message: Type2Mesage) {
        log.warn("Received a Type2Mesage ")
        val someClassObj = SomeClass()
        someClassObj.publicMethod(message)
    }   
}
```

How can I test this? or there is no need to do Unit Testing here? I wrote some integration testing to see whether the listener is working but it did not work. Appreciate expert's advise.

Comment: `kafka-clients` comes with MockProducer + MockConsumer for unit tests. You don't need Spring to test Kafka code. Otherwise, EmbeddedKafka with `spring-kafka`, or TestContainers can be used for integration testing. But "yes", you _should_ test your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write a unit test to call that `process()` method directly.
Then you can verify what is going on in that `someClassObj.publicMethod()`.

Yes, you can write an integration test to produce and consume data over Apache Kafka, but you need to keep in mind that this listener method is called on a listener container thread, so to verify data in the end you need some async barrier.

Comment: but `processMessageType2()` is a private method. How to verify the ´someClassObj.publicMethod().´? Any sample?

Comment: Right, it is `private`, but looks like it calls that `someClassObj.publicMethod()`. You need to understand what is going on in the end with your data to be exact in verification. I doubt that it is just ignored in the end. It might be stored into DB, or at least logged. If we know more about your `someClassObj.publicMethod()` logic, we may give you some idea. But in general it sounds like you need learn what is unit testing at all.

Comment: Imagine that method is taking some values from the message, and apply logic then store some data into DB. You meant to write tests for the `publicMethod` ? So no need to do any unit testing for any method in the ´KafkaConsumerService´ ?

Comment: I see that you have a logic like ` when (message.type) {` in that `process()` method of the `KafkaConsumerService`. So, exactly this one would be a unit coverage. Since this method is `void` you only can verify its logic by the outcome of that `someClassObj.publicMethod()`. If you say store to DB, then it is OK to do `SELECT` in your test for the data just inserted after your `process()` call.